# I got my Activity Dark When I use "Navigation-Drawer" KOTLIN

Tags: kotlin, android-activity, navigation

I'm using a `navigation` component but when I click an Item to load an activity it starts in dark screen and I don't know what's going on?

[image]

View works only when I press the square to "resume my app" and I don't really know where's the mistake

[image]

[image]

This is my code

navigation.xml

```
<activity
    android:id="@+id/mn_log_out"
    android:name="mx.MyApp.android.LogOutMessageActivity"
    android:label="LogOutMessageActivity" />
```

**mx.MyApp.android.LogOutMessageActivity**

```
   @SuppressLint("ResourceType", "CommitPrefEdits")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        builder.setTitle(resources.getString(R.string.log_out_title))
        builder.setMessage(resources.getString(R.string.log_out_description))

        val dialogClickListener = DialogInterface.OnClickListener { _, which ->
            when (which) {
                DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE -> logOut()
            }
        }

        builder.setPositiveButton(resources.getString(R.string.yes), dialogClickListener)
        builder.setNegativeButton(resources.getString(R.string.no), dialogClickListener)

        dialog = builder.create()
        dialog.show()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the build.gradle

I made downgrade to this libraries. We need to report this issue on the newest version

THIS

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0"
```

INSTEAD

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.1"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.1"
```